# Android CSV Path is throwing FileNotFoundExpception

Tags: android, csv, filenotfoundexception, import-from-csv

I want to import csv from external storage and then update my database but when I am selecting that csv from downloaded folder `FileNotFoundExpception` comes. Here is the exception System.err:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: /document/primary:Download/GuestCSV.csv: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Here is my code. Kindly review my code and help me to find a solution.

```
        importDatabase.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            intent.setType("text/*");
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open CSV"), ACTIVITY_CHOOSE_FILE);
        }
    });
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case ACTIVITY_CHOOSE_FILE: {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                onImport(new File(data.getData().getPath()));
                Log.d(TAG, data.getData().getPath());
            }
        }
    }
}

public void onImport(File files) {
    try {
        String[] nextLine;
        try {
            CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(files.getAbsolutePath()));
            while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
                // nextLine[] is an array of values from the line
                String emailID = nextLine[0];
                String guestName = nextLine[1];
                String guestSource = nextLine[2];
                String guestPhone = nextLine[3];
                String guestCount = nextLine[4];
                String guestCreatedDate = nextLine[5];
                String guestModifiedDate = nextLine[6];
                GuestDetails guestDetails = new GuestDetails();
                guestDetails.setEmail(emailID);
                guestDetails.setUsername(guestName);
                guestDetails.setPhone(guestPhone);
                guestDetails.setSource(guestSource);
                guestDetails.setCount(Integer.valueOf(guestCount));
                guestDetails.setCreatedDate(guestCreatedDate);
                guestDetails.setModifiedDate(guestModifiedDate);
                try {
                    helper.insertGuest(guestDetails);
                } catch (SQLiteConstraintException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data inserted into table...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: do you have permission to read external storage?

Comment: You are trying to access the wrong path: `/document/primary:Download/GuestCSV.csv`? The sd card is typically mounted under `/mnt/somedevicename/`

Comment: @BobMalooga actually he gets the path from android, actually it should be ok. But you're right, the path seems to be wrong

Comment: yes sir i have given all the permission necessary. I tried all getPath(), getAbsolutePath() but nothing is working for me. Please suggest me something...

Comment: @BobMalooga sir even i tried passing this path i am getting same response. content:/com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary%3ADownload%2FGuestCSV.csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no guaranty that the URI you are receiving as result is a file (and thus that the path part is an actual filesystem path).

It may be a `content:` URI, in with case the path only makes sense for the corresponding `ContentProvider`.

This kind of URI should be read using [ContentResolver.openInputStream()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#openInputStream%28android.net.Uri%29) or queried via [ContentResolver.query()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#query%28android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String%29).

See [A Uri Is Not (Necessarily) a File](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/07/04/uri-not-necessarily-file.html) for more details.

Comment: What did you exactly do ? I checked some time ago and the `com.android.externalstorage.documents` provider does support opening a stream, but you can not get a path

Comment: I write this                if (uri != null && "content".equals(uri.getScheme())) {
                    Cursor cursor = this.getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[]{android.provider.MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA}, null, null, null);
                    cursor.moveToFirst();
                    filePath = cursor.getString(0);
                    cursor.close();
                } else {
                    filePath = uri.getPath();
                }
                CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(filePath));

Comment: what happens with `new CSVReader(new InputStreamReader(getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri)));` ?

Comment: or  better `new CSVReader(new InputStreamReader(new BufferedInputStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri))));`